# Problems Creating My Own UITableViewController Abstract Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, abstract-class

I am creating a custom UITableViewController (SATableViewController) class that I can inherit from that will alert me as to when I should resign first responder from text fields, etc.

However, upon loading of the view (viewDidLoad, `[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:_tapGestureRecognizer];` line indicated in the code below) the following exception is thrown:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`

The gesture recognizer is alloc'ed and initialized just fine, so I am stumped as to why this is occurring. This gesture recognizer stuff was all part of RootTableViewController and it worked just fine.

This is what I have (relevant portions):

**SATableViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SATableViewController : UITableViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@end
```

**SATableViewController.m:**

```
@interface SATableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;

@end

@implementation SATableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // add gesture to detect when table view is being tapped so that keyboard may be dismissed
    self.tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    _tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    _tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:_tapGestureRecognizer]; // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
}

//...

//see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195661/why-is-uigesturerecognizer-being-called-on-my-textfield-clear-button
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] ||
       [touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    // to be overidden by subclass -- called when text field should be dismissed
}

//...

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)activeScrollView {
    [self dismissKeyboard];
}
```

**RootTableViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SATableViewController.h"

@interface RootTableViewController : SATableViewController

@end
```

**RootTableViewController.m:**

```
@interface RootTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;

@end

@implementation RootTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    if ([_textField isFirstResponder]) {
        [_textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
//...
```

Comment: Please check your data source, the exception indicates the problem in your data source, other implementations are clean.

Comment: You should not be using _tapGestureRecognizer anywhere except in an initializer. Have you tried replacing _tapGestureRecognizer with self.tapGestureRecognizer ?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. It was because I didn't get rid of `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;` in **RootTableViewController.m**.

So

```
@interface RootTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;

@end
```

Should have been

```
@interface RootTableViewController ()

@end
```